# How to create branch and push to server

Tags: git

I have cloned project from repo and I need to create branch and in that branch do my changes. After that I need to push that branch on repo. How to do this ? I am sorry, I am new to git ?

Comment: @Mark Longair is correct if you want the branch stored on the remote. Even though you used the word push I get the feeling you are meaning to "push" the changes from your local branch back into the master on the remote repo?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can create a new branch called `my-work` (based on your current commit) and switch to that branch with:

```
git branch my-work
git checkout my-work
```

Or, as a shortcut for those two commands, you can just do:

```
git checkout -b my-work
```

To push that branch to the repository that you cloned from, you should do:

```
git push origin my-work
```

`origin` is a nickname for the repository you cloned from.  It's known as a "remote", in git terminology.  *Update: a clarification due to Michael Minton's helpful comment above: this will push your `my-work` branch to a branch called `my-work` in the remote repository, creating it if necessary - if you meant something different, it would be best to edit your question to clarify that point.*

The first time you do that push command, you may want to do `git push -u origin my-work`, which sets configuration options that make the branch `my-work` in the `origin` repository considered as the default "upstream" branch for your `my-work` branch.  (You don't need to worry about that for the moment if you're new to git, but it will mean that git provides more helpful status information and various commands have more useful default actions.)